# I am trying to login to a remote host and executing some commands, but the script is getting hanged

Tags: python

I am trying to login to a remote host and trying to execute few commands, but the problem is that after executing the script, it is getting hanged. And for the information i want to do that with telnetlib, not anything other like paramiko. When i remove all the commands other than "ls" and "exit", it does not hang and get connected as well as executes both the commands. Can anybody explain me the behaviour. What am i doing wrong and how can it be resolved. i want all these commands to execute as i need to change the password of the remote machine through this script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import telnetlib


HOST = "localhost"

user = 'root'
chpassword = 'ddfvt123'
password = 'passw0rd'

    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

    tn.read_until("login: ")
    tn.write(user + "\n")
    if password:
        tn.read_until("Password: ")
        tn.write(password + "\n")
    tn.write("ls\n")
    tn.write("chpasswd -c\n")
    tn.write("{}:{}".format(user, chpassword))
    tn.write("\cD")
    tn.write("exit\n")
    print tn.read_all()
```

Answer (score 0):

> Telnet instances have the following methods:
>
> `Telnet.read_until(expected[, timeout])`
>
> Read until a given string, `expected`, is encountered or until `timeout` seconds have passed.
>
> When no match is found, return whatever is available instead, possibly the empty string. Raise EOFError if the connection is closed and no cooked data is available.

I think you just never found the "login" or "password" strings. Trying putting print statements in between your code to find out where it's stuck at.